# How to get an array type [1,2] instead of (1, 2) in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, jsonmodel

I'm trying to send an array in post JSONModel call. I need convett my array to NSString and send the array in format:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

but when I convert this to NSString and print my array, this has the format:

```
(1, 2, 3)


NSMutableArray *array= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
NSString *arraString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", arr];
NSLog(@"%@",arraString);
```

How can I create this with `[]` format?

Comment: Use the `NSJSONSerialization` class to serialize json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
NSData *jsond = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:NULL];
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsond encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

Comment: How could I avoid the \n when I add my json array serialized to params in my call?, I'm getting: "[\n  1,\n  2,\n  3,\n  4\n]" instead of [ 1, 2,  3,  4]

Comment: Remove the 'pretty print' option from my code snippet and replace it with a 0.

Comment: That's NSData yo (and probably doesn't actually contain a t)... Convert it to an NSString and print it. See last line of my code)

Comment: ...actually the second-to-last line (beginning with NSString *json...)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
NSString *joinedString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *arraString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", joinedString];
```

Hope this will fix your problem