# How to send in postJson an array like string without "" in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, nsjsonserialization, jsonmodel

I need send to my request server an array in parameters, but this can't be contained between "".

I need send to my server the key users with the array [2, 5, 6] value like this:

```
"users" : [2, 5, 6]
```

I'm  trying do this but I only can get the array in format ( 2, 5, 6) or like this:

```
 "[2, 5, 6]"
```

---

This code only get the array with "":

```
NSMutableArray *array= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
NSData *jsond = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:NULL];
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsond encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

How can I send my array in parameters in the correct format without ""?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing what you are printing and how is was created, and your printed it (to see the quotes).

Comment: I'm updated my question with my code. Now I can show my array with "", but I can send this in parameters post json without ""

Comment: Does the value of `json` have the unwanted quotes?

Comment: That code doesn't output what we're seeing. Where is "users" coming from? Can you send the actual code please?

Comment: I had explained bad, "users" is the key of the dictionary that I want send to my server, but this questions is for convert the array to format [1,2,3] and add this array to the key "users"

Comment: Take the string, "[1,2,3]", and run it through NSJSONSerialization . Then you will have an NSArray. Add that to your NSMutableDictionary, under the key "users". I still don't quite know what you're doing but it sounds like maybe you're inserting JSON strings into things that should be holding arrays. The full code would help.

Comment: down voted because the question is unclear, the sample code doesn't generate the output in the question, and also this Q is very similar to OP's other Q asked a few hours ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539360/how-to-get-an-array-type-1-2-instead-of-1-2-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you need in question text try the following

```
NSDictionary *dict= @{@"users" : @[@1, @2, @3, @4]};
NSData *jsond = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsond encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The output is `{"users":[1,2,3,4]}`